# How can i set a default selection in PrimeNG Treetable

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, primeng-treetable

I want to set the selection with the value i get from Local-Storage.
Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<p-treeTable [value]="tableDataRow$ | async"
               [columns]="checkColumnNotFixed()"
               selectionMode="single"
               [(selection)]="selectedRow"
>
```

**TS:**

```
public selectedRow;

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedRow = LocalStorageSelectedRow;
  }
```

The value is set and can be shown in the console, but in the UI, the row is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my answer could help someone, but the thing that I do is assign to the model variable (selected row in this example) the values which I want to be selected. also I set a variable in the component called "compareSelectionBy", and set its value with "deepEquals".

Example :
in the ts

```
this model =[ 
      { data: { name: 'Applications', size: '200mb', type: 'Folder' } },
      { data: { name: 'Angular', size: '25mb', type: 'Folder' } },
      { data: { name: 'Cloud', size: '20mb', type: 'Folder' } },
      { data: { name: 'backup-1.zip', size: '10mb', type: 'Zip' } },
      { data: { name: 'backup-2.zip', size: '10mb', type: 'Zip' } },]
```

in the html:

```
<p-treeTable
  [value]="items"
  [columns]="to.columns"
  selectionMode="checkbox"
  [(selection)]="model"
  [paginator]="to.paginator"
  [rows]="to.rows"
  (onNodeSelect)="onNodeSelect()"
  (onNodeUnselect)="onNodeUnselect()"
  compareSelectionBy="deepEquals"
  #tt
></p-treeTable>
```